# IBM Worklight - adapter throwing authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Using IBM Social Business Toolkit,

I'm using an OAuth adapter and Cordova InAppBrowser plugins to implement an OAuth flow and am seeing a very odd error when my adapter attempts to get the access token. First, it takes forever for the page to load, then it fails with the following error:

> [WARNING ] Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these
>   challenges: {}

Looking further it says there is a:

> 401 "Callback URI sent with the request is not the same as the one
>   registered for this Company App"

Answer (score 1):

This one took HOURS to figure out and the answer was an extra space!  In our worklight adapter we were pulling the values for our OAuth credentials from the worklight.properties file.  Our client_uri value had an extra space at the end of the value.  Which was causing it not to match the expected value.  Removing the space worked.  Seems like both the Worklight side AND the social business toolkit side should have handled the trim.  But at least we figured out our problem.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. I have registered in our tracking system a request to verify our parsers and ensure that the properties are properly trimmed.

Comment: As a follow up to this question, Worklight 6.2 properly trims properties in the worklight.properties file.